# how to access parent variables in php

Tags: php, class, oop, parent, extend

I don't know if this question has been asked before, but i have been looking for it and i couldnt see anything.

My problem is as follow:

I have two classes. The father class (Products.php) contains the following code:

```
class Producto {
    protected $id;
    protected $producto;
    protected $descripcion;

//CONSTRUCT FUNCTION
    function __construct($id, $prod, $description){
        $this->id=$id;
        $this->producto=$prod;
        $this->descripcion=$description;

    }
    //THE NEXT TO METHODS LOOK FOR IN THE DATABASE AND UPDATE THE PROPERTIES VARIABLES
    public static function db_select_producto_by_id($mysqli,$id){
        $query="SELECT * FROM tb_productos WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
        return Producto::db_select($mysqli,$query);
    }

    public static function db_select_producto_by_name($mysqli,$name){
        $query="SELECT * FROM tb_productos WHERE producto='$name' LIMIT 1";
        return Producto::db_select($mysqli,$query);
    }

    protected static function db_select($mysqli, $query)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                 $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 return new Producto($row['id'], $row['producto'], $row['descripcion']);
            }else
                 return new Producto(0, 'none', 'none');
    }
```

The child class (Oferta.php) extends from Producto.php and contains the following code:

```
class Oferta extends Producto{

    protected $idOferta;
    protected $tipoOferta;
    protected $precioOferta;
    protected $descripcionOferta;


    function _construct($idOferta, $tipoOferta, $precioOferta, $descripcionOferta, $id,$prod,$descripcion){
        $this->idOferta=$idOferta;
        $this->tipoOferta=$tipoOferta;
        $this->precioOferta=$precioOferta;
        $this->descripcionOferta=$descripcionOferta;

        parent::__construct($id,$prod,$descripcion);
    }

    //METHODS THAT SELECT FROM THE DATABASE

    public static function db_oferta_by_ofertaId($mysqli, $idOferta)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM tb_ofertas WHERE id=".$idOferta;
        return self::db_select($mysqli, $query); 
    }

    public static function db_oferta_by_productoId($mysqli, $productoId)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM tb_ofertas WHERE idproducto=".$productoId;
        return self::db_select($mysqli, $query); 
    }


    protected static function db_select($mysqli, $query)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                 $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//MY PROBLEM IS HERE, BECAUSE I WANT TO ACCESS THE THE PARENTS VARIABLES TO RETURN AN OFERTA CLASS READING ALL THE VALUES FROM THE DATABASE
                 $producto=parent::db_select_producto_by_id($mysqli,$row['idproducto']);
                 return new Oferta($row['id'], $row['tipooferta'], $row['preciooferta'], $row['descripcionoferta'], $producto->id, $producto->producto, $producto->descripcion);
            }else
                 return new Oferta(0, 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none');
    }
```

As you can see in the method db_select from Oferta class, i cant access to the parents properties once i have readed from the database. 
i would apreciate any solution, thank you in advance

Comment: which variable are you trying to access? I don't get it..

Comment: Any errors happening?

Comment: it doesnt have any errors, it is wrong because the method 'db_select($mysqli,$query)' should load the values readed from the DB to the variables of the class. In the father class it works, but it doesnt in Oferta, because i dont know how to execute the Producto::db_select() method and use the retuened value in the child class

Comment: what i want to do is something like this:

Comment: I get the following result when it reads from my DB:

Oferta Object ( [idOferta:protected] => [tipoOferta:protected] => [precioOferta:protected] => [descripcionOferta:protected] => [id:protected] => 2 [producto:protected] => la mejon [descripcion:protected] => 20.000 )

The first 4 variables dont get values, but i dont know why. I have tried everything and checked the code 1000 times. Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the method of the class you're extending from by just calling it on the $this object:

```
$this->db_select_producto_by_id($mysqli,$row['idproducto']);
```

Comment: no, sorry, but it doesnt work because i cant use $this in statics methods.

Comment: Apologies, should have spotted that. self:: and parent:: should both work. Are you sure there's no errors at all, have you turned error reporting on and/or inspected the error log file? I've tested it locally and it works fine for me.

Comment: yes, i tried, but it still doesnt work, i dont know what to do yet. I think the key is in the reserved words parent and self, but something is wrong in my logic.

Comment: I have done some changes, but still not working. It doesnt give me any error, but I still dont get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

The code writen above is right, the problem was that i had just **one simple underline** in construct function of Oferta class. **Construct function needs two underlines before its name**.

The **construct** of Oferta should be like this:

```
function __construct($idOferta, $tipoOferta, $precioOferta, $descripcionOferta, $id,$prod,$descripcion){
    $this->idOferta=$idOferta;
    $this->tipoOferta=$tipoOferta;
    $this->precioOferta=$precioOferta;
    $this->descripcionOferta=$descripcionOferta;

    parent::__construct($id,$prod,$descripcion);
}
```

As you can see, now the function is correctly written.